# Precision improvement -- sequence plot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot the graph of a sequence relating to continuous compounding with some annual interest rate and an input capital. However, it seems that the precision of the generated plot is insufficient (see the graph fluctuations below).

***Output:***

[image]

***MWE:***

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}%

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\begin{axis}[%
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=center,
    tick align=outside,
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
    xtickmax=55,
    ytickmin=2100,
    ytickmax=2103,
    ymin=2098,
    enlargelimits=true,
    mark size=1pt,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,}}
    ]
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=1:55,
    samples=55,
    only marks,
    orange!50,
    draw=black] {2000*(1+0.05/x)^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

***Question:***

Is there any (simple) way for improving the precision of the `\addplot`-command (possibly without gnuplot)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach letting [`xint`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) do the computations.

Fortunately only integer (half-integers would be ok) exponents are needed. Indeed, `xint` still waits for addition of support of mathematical functions such as log and exp.

Advantage is that it works will all engines (I used pdflatex).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\usepackage{xintexpr}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\begin{axis}[%
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=center,
    tick align=outside,
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
    xtickmax=55,
    ytickmin=2100,
    ytickmax=2103,
    ymin=2098,
    enlargelimits=true,
    mark size=1pt,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,}}
    ]
\xintDigits:=8;% no need to use 16 digits of precision
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
%    domain=1:55,
%    samples=55,
    only marks,
    orange!50,
    draw=black] coordinates {%
      \xintthecoords% (converts x1,y1,x2,y2,... into (x1, y1) (x2, y2)...
                    %  format, as expected by "coordinates")
      \xintfloatexpr 
          seq((x,2000*(1+0.05/x)^x), x=1..55)
          % works with xint float engine
          % because exponent is integer (or half-integer)
      \relax
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your approach works fine for me. I slightly changed the setting of precision digits to `\xintDigits:=10`. Now, the result is perfect for my needs.

Comment: luckily there were no sine or cosine... they need to be added to xint. If you entirely drop the `\xintDigits` line, computations will be done with `16` digits of (floating point) precision. It is also possible to set it to higher than `16` but of course this has no interest for plotting here and would only slow down pgfplots code parsing the coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Warning: This answer is LuaLaTeX-based.

`pgfplots` warns you about one important detail: You should use a newer compatibility setting. Just copying the line from the warning to the file solves the fluctuations (as `pgpfplots` will use Lua to calculate the points).

[image: compatibility mode]

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\begin{axis}[%
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=center,
    tick align=outside,
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
    xtickmax=55,
    ytickmin=2100,
    ytickmax=2103,
    ymin=2098,
    enlargelimits=true,
    mark size=1pt,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,}}
    ]
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=1:55,
    samples=55,
    only marks,
    orange!50,
    draw=black] {2000*(1+0.05/x)^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is only true, if you run your code with LuaLaTeX, because with `compat=1.12` or higher then Lua is used for the calculation. Of course Lua can't be used when compiling with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Oops, there's a drawback having LuaLaTeX as default compiler :| I'll edit the post.

Comment: @TeXnician: Thank you for your reply. I forgott to mention the fact that I'm using pdfLaTeX (TeXLive 2017). Adding the line `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` to my source does not change anything in the output in combination with pdfLaTeX. Unfortunatelly, I have no experiences with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @MarianG. No problem, most people use pdflatex, I just forgot that the compatibility option is only relevant for lualatex for the reason Stefan Pinnow mentioned. Luckily jfbu's answer will work, so everything is fine :)